# Добавление массива в массив array_merge()

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 100
            [wallet] =>  38068569756ф
            [sum] => 14500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 101
            [wallet] => + 3255454555
            [sum] => 14500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 102
            [wallet] =>  3255455445
            [sum] => 14500
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 103
            [wallet] =>  32554554522
            [sum] => 14500
        )
```

и второй массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 9
            [wallet] => +380685697562
            [sum] => 2000
        )

)
```

мне нужно добавить второй в конец первого, делаю через `array_merge()` но есть проблема, у меня первый массив лежит в переменной `$var1`, второй в `$var2`, если я делаю `$var1 = array_merge($var1, $var2);` то приходит пустой массив, а если я делаю `$var3 = array_merge($var1, $var2)` то `$var3` возвращает то что мне нужно, а мне нужно чтобы обязательно функция возвращала `$var1`

**UPDATE- привел примеры массивов**
Вот массивы, `var1 merged` я присваиваю значение с переменной `Variable merged`, но по итогу `Variable merged` остается с данными а `var1 merged`  пустой массив

```
var1 before = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 100
            [wallet] =>  38068569756ф
            [sum] => 14500
        )

)
var2 before = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 54
            [wallet] =>  380685697563
            [sum] => 10500
        )

)

var1 merged = Array
(
)
Variable merged = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 100
            [wallet] =>  38068569756ф
            [sum] => 14500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idwallets] => 54
            [wallet] =>  380685697563
            [sum] => 10500
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты решения

1) Использовать дополнительную переменную, а потом переприсвоить ее

```
$var3 = array_merge($var1, $var2);
$var1 = $var3;
```

2) Использовать 1 вариант но в своей функции

```
function my_array_merge(&$base, $addend) {
  $var3 = array_merge($var1, $var2);
  $var1 = $var3;
  return $var1;
}
```

3) Использовать `array_push` или `[]`

```
foreach ($var2 as $item)
  $var1[] = $item;
```

**UPDATE**
Автор вопроса ввел в заблуждение. Вот такой код

```
$var1 = [
  [1, 1],
  [2, 2],
  [3, 3]
];
$var2 = [
  [5, 5],
  [6, 6]
];
echo 'var1 = ';
print_r($var1);
echo 'var2 = ';
print_r($var2);
$var1 = array_merge($var1, $var2);
echo 'var1(merged) = ';
print_r($var1);
```

Отлично выполняется и выводит такой результат

```
var1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )
)
var2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
        )
)
var1(merged) = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Comment: Первый вариант пробовал, не работает! сейчас попробую через функцию

Comment: @rodgers что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Когда я делаю через присвоение с другой переменной , то возвращает пустой массив

Comment: @rodgers приведите код с выводом `var_dump()` массивов до объединения и после. Посмотрите обновление моего ответа. Все работает со стандартным `array_merge()`

Comment: Вот привел примеры

Comment: @rodgers не вижу кода. Вижу только выводы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47325/discussion-between-rodgers-and-anton-shchyrov).